# Python tic-tac-toe

Tags: python, algorithm, function, tic-tac-toe

tac-toe game in python2, but I can't stop the game when the program meets 3-Xs or 3-Os
This is my code here :

```
a=[]
for i in range(0,10):
    a.append(" ")
def table():
    print "  " + a[1]+ "  |  " +a[2]+ "  |  " +a[3] +"  "
    print "-----------------"
    print "  " + a[4]+ "  |  " +a[5]+ "  |  " +a[6] +"  "
    print "-----------------"
    print "  " + a[7]+ "  |  " +a[8]+ "  |  " +a[9] +"  "



table()
#x = None
def play():
    global x
    for i in range(1,10):
        x= None
        if (i%2==1):
            while ((x>9 or x<0) ):
                x=int(raw_input("Player1, it's your turn : "))
            while ((a[x]=="O" or a[x]=="X")):
                x=int(raw_input("Player1, it's your turn : "))
            a[x]='X'
            table()

        if (i%2==0):
            while ((x>9 or x<0) ):
                x=int(raw_input("Player2, it's your turn : "))
            while ((a[x]=="O" or a[x]=="X")):
                x=int(raw_input("Player2, it's your turn : "))
            a[x]='O'
            table()

            if win() or win2():
                return



def win():
    if (a[1]=="X" and a[2]=="X" and a[3]=="X") or \
     (a[4]=="X" and a[5]=="X" and a[6]=="X") or \
     (a[7]=="X" and a[8]=="X" and a[9]=="X") or \
     (a[1]=="X" and a[4]=="X" and a[7]=="X") or \
     (a[2]=="X" and a[5]=="X" and a[8]=="X") or \
     (a[3]=="X" and a[6]=="X" and a[9]=="X") or \
     (a[1]=="X" and a[5]=="X" and a[9]=="X") or \
     (a[3]=="X" and a[5]=="X" and a[7]=="X") : print "PLAYER1 WON, Congratulations !!!"

#######


def win2():
    if (a[1]=="O" and a[2]=="O" and a[3]=="O") or \
     (a[4]=="O" and a[5]=="O" and a[6]=="O") or \
     (a[7]=="O" and a[8]=="O" and a[9]=="O") or \
     (a[1]=="O" and a[4]=="O" and a[7]=="O") or \
     (a[2]=="O" and a[5]=="O" and a[8]=="O") or \
     (a[3]=="O" and a[6]=="O" and a[9]=="O") or \
     (a[1]=="O" and a[5]=="O" and a[9]=="O") or \
     (a[3]=="O" and a[5]=="O" and a[7]=="O"): print "PLAYER2 WON, Congratulations !!!"



    #else: print "Egalitate !!!"



def egal():
    if (not win() and not win2() ):
        print "Egalitate !" 





play()
#win()
#egal()
```

As you see I've coded :

```
if win() or win2():
    return
```

Unfortunately it doesn't quit the program when it meets either one TRUE.

Comment: You're not return anything from those functions, so it always returns `None`.

Comment: Yes but I need to exit the function play(), I did return in order to quit the function...

Comment: But you're not returning anything from `win()` or `win2()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`win` should return a Boolean value indicating whether the player wins

```
def win():
    return (a[1]=="X" and a[2]=="X" and a[3]=="X") or \
     (a[4]=="X" and a[5]=="X" and a[6]=="X") or \
     (a[7]=="X" and a[8]=="X" and a[9]=="X") or \
     (a[1]=="X" and a[4]=="X" and a[7]=="X") or \
     (a[2]=="X" and a[5]=="X" and a[8]=="X") or \
     (a[3]=="X" and a[6]=="X" and a[9]=="X") or \
     (a[1]=="X" and a[5]=="X" and a[9]=="X") or \
     (a[3]=="X" and a[5]=="X" and a[7]=="X")
```

In `play` you call `win`, and if it returns `TRUE`, then `print` and `return`.

```
if win():
    print "PLAYER1 WON, Congratulations !!!"
    return
```

You can of course do the same for `win2`.